# navigation wants to be left aligned

Tags: html, css, web

I want my navigation to be left aligned inside a div with the class `aside`. I want it to be aligned just like my paragraph in my div with the  class `aside`. but the navigation is sitting more towards right side. can anyone sort it out for me?

```
.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    }

.sidebar li{ width:100%;list-style-type: none;border-bottom:1px white solid;}
.sidebar a:link, a:visited {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: royalblue;
  /*    width: 120px;  */

    text-align: center;
    padding: 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    }
.sidebar a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #7A991A;
    color:black;
} 

.aside
    {
         float: left; 
         /* overflow:hidden; */
        width: 20%;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        border:thin royalblue solid;
        background-color:grey;

    }
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="aside">
             <div><p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraphp aragrap hparag raph paragraph</p></div> 

                <ul class="sidebar">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="solar.html">Solar</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Hendrer</a></li>
                        </ul>


                </div>
```

Fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z0bwuhqr/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was with your class declaration for the UL
Make changes in CSS

```
.sidebar ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width:100%;
    }
```

Edit this like

```
ul.sidebar  {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width:100%;
    }
```

Please refer updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/z0bwuhqr/2/

Comment: Thanks it is working.. also the  background color in a:active is not working for active  link. it appears white instead what I mentioned in a:active. can you tell me what is wrong with that?

Comment: if you are expecting that green color should be set as background color that is working on hover.

Comment: But I expect it to show green bg color on active class as well.

Comment: you mean to say after click background color should be green?

Answer (score 1):

**Please try this**

Add the following style.

```
.aside
    {
        width: 40%;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        border:thin royalblue solid;
        background-color:grey;

    }
.test{
    width:50%;
    float:left;    
}
.clearFix{
    clear:both;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="aside">

    <div class="test">
        <ul class="sidebar" style="padding-left:5px;">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="solar.html">Solar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hendrer</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div> 
    <div class="test"><p>paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraph paragraphp aragrap hparag raph paragraph</p></div>
    <div class="clearFix"></div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Rino_Raj/mf279tnw/6/)